# MVC 5.0 Models - have a field point to enum choices based on logic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I am new to MVC 5.0 and C# sharp. For learning purposes, I am building a list of cars.

In my models I have the following below. In a real life situation, there would be many(to many) models if I combined them all in a single enum.

How would I(or is it possible) to implement some logic where if a user pics model 'Buick' from makes that it would point to a specific enum like `enum BuickModels {}`?

```
namespace ListApp3.Models
{
    enum Models { Eclave, Encore, Acadia}
    enum Makes { Buick, GMC }
    enum Types { coupe, sedan }
}

public class Cars
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Types Type { get; set; }
    public Makes Make { get; set; }
    public Models Model { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Mileage { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your best bet would be to create a `Make` class, with the `Makes` enum as a property on it. You would also have a `Model` class that has the `Models` enum in that object. Your `Make` class would then have a `Models` enumerable property that contains all of the appropriate Models.

Comment: So if I understand well, you wish to have like a dropdownlist that shows the _Makes_ and when you choose a value in there, you have another ddl populated with values from another enum related to the previous selection, am I correct?

Comment: @Wail yes, that is correct. In real life situation, a single emu that contains all models for every make would be huge. So, it would be a more correct design to have a enum Models per a make of vehicle.

Comment: @dman Have you tried to model this in database? In my opinion it can suit your usecase better.